# Getting an error: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

The code is supposed to copy the contents in folder 1 to folder 2 using an Apache Camel Route that is triggered using Quartz. When I run the program, I get these errors:
'org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springCamelApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'camelContext'' and 'Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camelContext' defined in class path resource [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@512ddf17].'

```
public class SpringCamelApplication {

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCamelApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FileRouteBuilder fileRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        FileRouteBuilder routeBuilder = new FileRouteBuilder();
        camelContext.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
        return routeBuilder;

    }
}
```

```
public class FileRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:R://folder1?recursive=true&noop=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *").process(new Processor() {

            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("transferring " + exchange.getIn().getBody());

            }
        }).to("file:R://folder2");
    }
}
```

```
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a problem with your Java version being incompatible with your Apache Camel version. Have you checked if your Apache camel supports your version of Java?

Java 8 is officially supported by Camel 2.x and may or may not work with Camel 3.x, whereas Java 11 is only officially supported by Camel 3.x

See: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html